# UIView animateWithDuration wait until animation finishes

Tags: ios, animation

I'm running an animation after a button touch. If the user touches the button before the current animation finishes I want the new animation to wait until the current animation finishes. How can I do so?

Answer (score 12):

Nest it with the completion variation of UIView's animateWithDuration wrapper like so:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.00 animations:^{
    //animate first!
    } 
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:1.00 animations:^{
                         //animate the second time.
                         }];
    }];
```

Or just set a single animation to continue from it's current state with this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.00 
                          delay:0.00 
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState 
                     animations:^{
                         //animate
                     } 
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){

    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

I always chain my animation with this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(animationDone) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
```